# .UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:7000 is not available

Tags: ip-address, cassandra

I tried to create a cluster with three Cassandra nodes on my machine.I have unpacked tar.gz and changed listen and rpc_addresses, also JMX_PORT.It did not work

```
~/apache-cassandra-3.11.1-1/bin$ nodetool -h 127.0.0.02 -p 8081 ring
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.02:8081' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

Then I followed ALex Ott;s adviced,installed ccm.Then I have problem again

```
ccm start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccm-3.1.3-py3.6.egg/ccmlib/common.py", line 513, in assert_socket_available
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/bin/ccm", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('ccm==3.1.3', 'ccm')
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 750, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1534, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccm-3.1.3-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ccm", line 105, in <module>
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccm-3.1.3-py3.6.egg/ccmlib/cmds/cluster_cmds.py", line 490, in run
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccm-3.1.3-py3.6.egg/ccmlib/cluster.py", line 389, in start
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccm-3.1.3-py3.6.egg/ccmlib/common.py", line 519, in assert_socket_available
ccmlib.common.UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:7000 is not available: [Errno 98] Address already in use; a cluster may already be running or you may need to add the loopback alias
```

How to check address the availability?

Comment: Before starting CCM, check if you have a Cassandra instance already running. If you do, kill it, then start CCM again.

Comment: @PedroGordo Should I kill or stop the process?

Comment: Kill it the process. That should open up the IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~/apache-cassandra-3.11.1-1/bin$ nodetool -h 127.0.0.02 -p 8081 ring
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.02:8081' - ConnectException: 
'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

127.0.0.02 does not look like a valid IP

Comment: It is same with 127.0.0.2.